# Return elements of a JSON object as an array

Tags: anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I have an XML file that is converted to a JSON object by a TRANSFORM MESSAGE:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload
```

The resulting JSON object has a format of:

```
{
  "Items": {
    "Item": {
      "ItemId": "123",
      "OrganizationId": "456",
      "OrganizationCode": "ABC",
```

where there is one "Items" and 112 "Item". What I want is to return an JSON array contains all of the ItemIds. I am attempting to use TRANSFORM MESSAGE within a FOREACH. The FOREACH has 'payload' in the collection field and TRANSFORM MESSAGE has:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
myItems: payload.items.*item map (item, index) -> {
    "myItemId" : item.ItemId
}
```

However, it always returns everything, the entire JSON object. I can't figure out if my FOREACH is wrong or if my TRANSFORM MESSAGE is wrong, but it always returns the entire JSON object.

---

An example of the incoming JSON would be:

```
{
  "Items": {
    "Item": {
      "ItemId": "8041",
      "OrganizationId": "12",
      "OrganizationCode": "ABC",
    },
    "Item": {
      "ItemId": "8050",
      "OrganizationId": "12",
      "OrganizationCode": "ABC",
    },
    "Item": {
      "ItemId": "3801",
      "OrganizationId": "12",
      "OrganizationCode": "ABC",
    }
  }
}
```

The output should be: ["8041", "8050", "3801"]. Parse the Item elements, extract the ItemID value and create a JSON array.

Comment: To be able to help you, please share the XML input. Note that there is no `foreach` in DataWeave. You are referring to  the `map()` function.

Comment: It is the FOR EACH module. The map() function is in a TRANSFORM MESSAGE inside the FOR EACH. But, I was just informed that the payload structure going into a FOR EACH is exactly the same as the payload structure coming out. I have to assign the JSON array that I am creating to a variable and use SET PAYLOAD to send the variable out.

Comment: In order to get the JSON array that is created within the FOR EACH module, do I have to create a global array outside and then assign the output of the map to this variable? Any examples of somebody doing this?

Comment: If the question is about the Foreach scope, you should add the input and the snippet including the foreach. However it seems easier to do this with the transformation you shared or something similar. If you share the input and expected output we could give it a try.

Comment: An example was added above. The actual ITEM element is huge (20K lines), but all I want is the item id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script works nearly well. Allow me to mention that the first transformation to convert from XML to JSON is counterproductive. The next transformation will have to parse JSON to emit JSON. It is better to do it in one step, from XML to JSON. If you need the intermediate result for some other processing, it is better to convert to Java (application/java), process, then when the final output is needed, then convert to the final JSON format. Processing intermediate steps in XML or JSON just consumes more resources.

Based on that I used the following XML input:

```
<Items>
    <Item>
        <ItemId>8041</ItemId>
        <OrganizationId>12</OrganizationId>
        <OrganizationCode>ABC</OrganizationCode>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <ItemId>8050</ItemId>
        <OrganizationId>12</OrganizationId>
        <OrganizationCode>ABC</OrganizationCode>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <ItemId>3801</ItemId>
        <OrganizationId>12</OrganizationId>
        <OrganizationCode>ABC</OrganizationCode>
    </Item>    
</Items>
```

Script:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.Items.*Item map (item, index) -> item.ItemId
```

Output:

```
[
  "8041",
  "8050",
  "3801"
]
```

The same script will work with your JSON input too.

Comment: Victory! That does exactly what I need! Just out of curiosity, what would I change to return an object instead of an array? Thank you much!

Comment: Something like `(payload.Items.*Item map (item, index) -> {ItemId: item.ItemId}) reduce ((i, accumulator={}) -> accumulator ++ i) `? It would return the same key multiple times, which is not nice to process later.